# MSSQL query to select ony those entries which are based on a criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I want to select only the row which is marked in **green**
Marked in **red** are those entries which should not be displayed

i.e selects only thoes rows from the table based on the following

1. Select entries which does not meet a criteria B_ID =188,198 and 82 and value for 82 = 'Referred' for a Client
2. order of B_Id can be diffent example 188,198,82 or 198,188,82
3. Note the group is based on column Client
4. If there exist entries with B_ID 188 or 198 or both for a client then i want to display them.

**Please note i am not allowed to use stored procedures here, everything has to be done with a query
Cannot use UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT within the query**
Find attached image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GEwc.png)

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What are your problems? Which version are you using: 2008 or 2014? Please provide some DDL/DML scripts if you want people to help you easily.

Comment: Please post some table structure, data sample and expected output.

Comment: I have added the image click on "enter image description here"

Comment: Why you are avoiding client 23 since the value is university for 82

Comment: the scenario is we are not interested in entries which has value other then Referred for any client.  we are interested in getting the result for those clients whose 82 value is not yet entered if entered it should not be 'university'

Comment: then you have to neglect both referred,university for the value 82 right?

Comment: yes neglect referred,university or anything else...ex if there are all 3 entries for client i.e B_id 182,198 and 82 it should be neglected.
 if there are entries i.e 182 and 198 for a client then it should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    *
from client
where client not in(select client from  client where B_ID=82 AND Value is not null)
```

Comment: what if i want only those rows which are marked as red and green excluding the last client who has value "University"

Comment: you want to select all the clients including both red and green except client(23) which is having the value "university" right?

Comment: yes right. all client who does not have value 82 inserted yet and if inserted it should be only 'Referred' noting else

Comment: select 
    *
from client
where client not in(select client from  client where B_ID=82 AND Value not in 'Referred')